# How to rename directories?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have created a folder within the Documents folder in my application directory .

I wanted to rename that folder through code,but not able to understand how to do it.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *oldDirectoryPath = @"Type your old directory Path";

NSArray *tempArrayForContentsOfDirectory =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:oldDirectoryPath error:nil];

NSString *newDirectoryPath = [[oldDirectoryPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]stringByAppendingPathComponent:newDirectoryname];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newDirectoryPath attributes:nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [tempArrayForContentsOfDirectory count]; i++)
{

NSString *newFilePath = [newDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[tempArrayForContentsOfDirectory objectAtIndex:i]];

NSString *oldFilePath = [oldDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[tempArrayForContentsOfDirectory objectAtIndex:i]];

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldFilePath toPath:newFilePath error:&error];

if (error) {
 // handle error
}

}
```

Comment: Apologies if I missed something somewhere, but don't you need to delete the old directory too?

Comment: @Peter Johnson: If you don't need to delete your old directory, then you can use the same code by replacing the line :[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldFilePath toPath:newFilePath error:&error]; to [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:oldFilePath toPath:newFilePath error:&error];.

Comment: the answer suggested by mackross is much more straightforward and less convoluted.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried?

```
    NString *newDirectoryName = @"<new folder name>";    
    NSString *oldPath = @"<path to the old folder>";
    NSString *newPath = [[oldPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newDirectoryName];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        // handle error
    }
```

Comment: how are you getting the path?

Comment: also are you getting an error? NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);

Comment: Does your path include the Documents directory path?

Comment: This works fine and is much less convoluted than the example given above. This should have been marked as the correct answer. +1

Comment: maybe this is already too old but I get an error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.) any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: NSFileNoSuchFileError = 4,                                              // Attempt to do a file system operation on a non-existent file

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

Using moveItemAtPath should work. Sometimes the directory isn't actually "renamed" but really moved to another place. In which case the target path directory structure needs to be created as well. 
Here a code snippet i'm using that works well :

```
-(BOOL)renameDir:(NSString *)dirPath asDir:(NSString *)newDirPath cleanExisting:(BOOL)clean
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (clean && [fm fileExistsAtPath:newDirPath])
    {
        [fm removeItemAtPath:newDirPath error:&error];
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while renameDir %@ as %@ :\n%@",dirPath,newDirPath,error);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    //Make sure container directories exist
    NSString *newDirContainer = [newDirPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:newDirContainer])
    {
      [fm createDirectoryAtPath:newDirContainer withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
     }

    if (error==nil)
    {
        [fm moveItemAtPath:dirPath toPath:newDirPath error:&error];
    }
    if (error!=nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"error while moveItemAtPath : %@",error);
    }
    return (error==nil);
}
```

Comment: It does not clean the old directory..does it ?

Answer (score 1):

This always work

```
NSLog (@"Copying download file from %@ to %@", aPath, bPath);
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: bPath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: bPath
                                                       error: &error];
        }

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: aPath
                                                     toPath: bPath
                                                      error: &error]){}
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: aPath
                                                       error: &error]) {}
```

Comment: This one has a side effect of duplicating the data. In case the data is big, or if the app crash in the middle of the operation, this could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is good article for renaming, deleting  and create files.

```
// For error information
   NSError *error;

// Create file manager
   NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
// Rename the file, by moving the file
   NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file2.txt"];

// Attempt the move
   if ([fileMgr moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:filePath2 error:&error] != YES)
       NSLog(@"Unable to move file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

// Show contents of Documents directory
     NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", 
     [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html