# Change app folder name

Tags: xcode, file-management

We would like to change the folder name of the current app. If my app is called abcCalc, I have an abcCalc parent folder and which contains the abcCalc.xcodeproj file, and also an abcCalc subfolder that contains the .m files, the .h files, image files, and so on.

I would like to change this abcCalc subfolder (that contains the code and support files) to a different name.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4486979/how-to-rename-directories

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed, renaming the app folder of an Xcode project is **not** straightforward. It certainly isn't as easy as just renaming the directory, because that directory name is referenced in a few places in the project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a subfolder within an Xcode project, all you need to is go to your project's Navigator (list of files) and select the folder you want to change (it's on the left side of the Xcode project window).  And on the right side of the project window you can bring up a "File Inspector".

The screen should look something like this:

[image: Click on Folder you want to change]

You can easily change the folder name by adjusting the field in "Group Name" in the File Inspector... or if you're more familiar with Xcode, double clicking on the selected folder name in the Navigator and change it there.

Comment: dang it... I added this answer before I realized it was a very likely duplicate.  Should I delete my answer and vote to close also?

Comment: I was referring to the SomeFineApp folder and which i changed, however the actually physical folder didn't change so that what got me curious to why. BTW, i'm not sure it's a dupe since i wasn't referring to the App name change per se. In any case thank you.

Comment: also i wasn't referring programmatically change as the dup link suggested. so thanks again.